# Ruby select random file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, discord

I have a folder with many pics. And now I'm setting up a new discordbot. The discord bot should select a random pic from the picfolder and post it.

I have configured the bot that he sends the pictures and now I need a random pic from the folder.

I'm currently so far that I can list the pictures what I have. But I always get all pictures not only one:

```
Dir.glob("/home/user/photo/*.jpg") do |image|
  bot.message(content: 'Ping!') do |bot|
  bot.respond image
end
```

Comment: Can you show some code? If you have an array (of pictures) you can call [`sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#sample-method) to get a random element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use [`#sample`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sample) here:

```rb
bot.respond Dir.glob("/home/user/photo/*.jpg").sample
```